# Conditional Mean Statement Across Dataframe

Tags: r, conditional-statements, lapply, mean, sapply

The following code will return the average conditioned that the months are greater than 6.

```
mean(df[df$delta1>6, "delta1"], na.rm=T)
```

Now, how do I do apply this for every column in the dataframe?

df:

```
delta1      delta2      delta3
NA          2           3
4           NA          6
7           8           NA
10          NA          12
NA          14          15
16          NA          18
19          20          NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apply-family of functions is useful here:

```
sapply(df, function(x) mean(x[x>6], na.rm=T))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can set the values in the dataframe which are less than equal to 6 to `NA` and count the mean using `colMeans` ignoring the `NA` values.

```
df[df <= 6] <- NA
colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)

#delta1 delta2 delta3 
#    13     14     15
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(delta1 = c(NA, 4L, 7L, 10L, NA, 16L, 19L), delta2 = c(2L, 
NA, 8L, NA, 14L, NA, 20L), delta3 = c(3L, 6L, NA, 12L, 15L, 18L, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: This is great! One thing though - I would like each column to be conditioned. If I am taking the mean of delta1, I want to make sure delta1 values > 6. If I am taking the mean of delta2, I want to make sure delta2 values > 6. Etc

Comment: I see. Sorry I misunderstood the question earlier. See my updated answer which should work I think.